# Use integrated terminal for debugging C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I would like to use the integrated terminal for debugging C++ files in VSCode on my Mac. I have the [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) added and enabled globally.

Here is the launch.json that I am using:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried adding `"console": "integratedTerminal"` to this with no change. When debugging a program, the terminal output says:

```
> Executing task: /usr/bin/clang++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -std=c++17 -g /Users/kris/learncpp/chapter_03/debugTest4.cpp -o /Users/kris/learncpp/chapter_03/debugTest4 <


Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Hitting any key here closes the terminal and drops me into a bash shell. Is there another setting I am missing somewhere?